# Nuxt3 can't use readBody() in server directory

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxt3

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const body = await readBody(event)
}
```

at server/routes/webhook.post.ts

I use Cloud Functions to put server.
When POST request send to the webhook, Cloud Functions receive this error...

```
[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of Object.
```

I hope someone could tell me how to solve it.
Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue too and came up with a solution to workaround the problem. It's not the best but it worked for me. Took me a while to figure it out because when logging `event.node.req.body` locally it always returns undefined but I could see in the cloud function logging it has a value

```
let body;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    body = await readBody(event);
} else {
    body = event.node.req.body;
}
```

Hope it helps.